# What's the code to retrieve IMSI using JavaME?

Tags: nokia, samsung-mobile, motorola

I need a JavaME code that will be able to retrieve IMSI.

Answer (score 0):

On Nokia devices you can access IMSI with the `com.nokia.mid.imsi` [system property](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Java/#!developers-guides/application-framework/system-properties/nokia-specific-system-properties.html). However access to this property is restricted to manufacturer/operator security domain